# Renaming files with an index in the bracket

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I'd like to write a short powershell script for renaming files like:

```
abc(1), abc(2), .., abc(10), ..,  abc(123), ..
```

to

`abc(001), abc(002), .., abc(010), .., abc(123), ..`

Any idea? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem abc* | Where {$_ -match 'abc\((\d+)\)'} | 
 Foreach {$num = [int]$matches[1]; Rename-Item $_ ("abc({0:000})" -f $num) -wh }
```

The Where stage of the pipeline is doing to two things.  First, only filenames that match the specified pattern are passed along.  Second, it uses a capture group to grab the numeric part of the name which is sitting in `$matches[1]`.

The Foreach stage applies script to each item, represented by `$_`, passed into it.  The first thing it does is to get the "numeric" part of the old filename.  Then it uses Rename-Item (PowerShell's rename command) to rename from the old name represented by $_ to the new name that is computed using a formatting string `"abc({0:000})" -f $num`.  In this case, the formatting directive goes in `{}` where 0 represents the position of the value specified after `-f`.  The `:000` is a formatting directive displays number with up to three leading zeros.  Finally the `-wh` is short for `-WhatIf` which directs potentially destructive operations like Rename-Item to show what it would do without actually doing anything.  Once you are satisfied the command is working correctly, remove the `-wh` and run it again.

Comment: It would be great if you provided a bit of explanation about some syntax in there, like the Rename-Item. Otherwise the above is line-noise without reading quite a lot of powershell doc.

Comment: Done.  Just wanted to get you a solution before I had to go run an errand.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Fully comprehensible explanation. Thanks:)